# Address checks within a partially untrusted application

Tags: c

Okay folks, I need your support.

I have an embedded C99 software, split over two cores.
One core (slave) is serving the other (master). The slave has to check all inputs, e.g., pointer addresses etc, it receives from the master before processing.
On an embedded target this is super easy thanks to linker scripts where all memory ranges are fixed/known, so I can easily set up my "allowed ranges".

Now the problem: I have to port this application to Desktop and this is where the fun begins.
The following constraints are unfortunately fixed and I have to stick to them.

- The firmware of both cores has to be merged into a single executable
- No multithreading, no multiple processes
- All address checks must still be enabled and effective

So I have to check at runtime, whether a pointer is pointing to "a specific half" of my program.
This can cover both static memory as well as stack (no heap allocations involved).
I can do all kinds of trickery outside of the original code, e.g., custom build scripts, arbitrary glue code etc.

Do you have any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: There's no portable way to validate addresses in C.

Comment: It's common to have "start" and "end" symbols for segments, although `dl_iterate_phdr` may be more useful if you have to deal with multiple objects. For heap, you can intercept all the allocation functions (malloc is just one of many, e.g. don't forget the aligned ones; also mmap syscall - hope nobody is bypassing libc for that).

Comment: What considered to be a valid address here?

Comment: @SergeyA addresses that point towards a few specific memory ranges on the master core

Comment: How does it even make sense to port MCU firmware to desktop? Also your requirements are nonsensical. Is this some bad school assignment?

Comment: @Lundin nope, this is real and the requirements are painful

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the person stating the requirements. That's not a technical problem we can help with.

Comment: There's no multithreading and no multiple processes? Explain how that works.

Comment: @user3386109 I am not allowed to spawn multiple threads or divide the application into multiple processes. What exactly do you need more information on?

Comment: You stated that the master and slave were running on different cores in the embedded system. Doesn't that mean that they were using multiple threads, or multiple processes?

Comment: In the original setup, there are separate hardware cores that run their code bare metal. Now I build and link them on Desktop into a single application and all core-communication is stubbed to simply directly forward data to the other part's interfaces

Comment: Ok, so master and slave are using the same stack. In the `main` function, you can get an approximate top-of-stack by taking the address of a local variable. Then presumably you'll call a function that is part of the master. The stub function that switches from master to slave can also take the address of a variable to approximate the bottom-of-master-stack.

Comment: I still don't see how you get back to the master code after invoking slave code. If master calls slave, and slave calls master, etc then you eventually just overflow the stack.

Comment: I would suggest just simulating all of it, essentially emulating as much of the hardware of the embedded target as you have to. Memory is just a (possibly sparse) array. You can easily implement a sparse array with bounds checking.

Comment: The other issue is that if master and slave are running in the same process, and the master is untrusted, the master can write garbage all over the slave's memory, and there's nothing the slave can do about it. (I'm assuming that in the embedded system, when the master writes garbage all over its own memory, it just crashes, and gets restarted.)

Comment: Thanks @user3386109 for your input! All master calls to the slave provide an output address and the slave simply writes to that but never calls the master. So stack overflow wont happen

Comment: Ahh, got it, that clears things up! There may be ways to get more accurate limits on the master's stack range (e.g. using inline assembly). You might want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Would you mind to provide a [example], with emphasis on "minimal" and "complete", please? Do you plan to port this back to the embedded system? What is the reasoning behind the requirement of checking addresses of a single-process application? What kind of addresses are these, on stack, on heap, static variables? If the two processes are merged into one single-process desktop application, you may try to write your own linker script based on existing ones.